# `Wrong type argument when using `org-agenda`

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have been using `org-agenda` with the setup from [here](http://doc.norang.ca/org-mode.html#CaptureTemplates). For some reason, I get the following error when I try to generate the basic `org-agenda` (`C-c a`). The agenda just shows up blank with no entries. The message is below.

```
org-agenda-list: Wrong type argument: listp, #("----------------" 0 16 (org-heading t))
```

The configuration in my `.spacemacs` file is below. When I comment it out then things work fine, but I was hoping to get this to work.

```
;; Enable display of the time grid so we can see the marker for the current time
(setq org-agenda-time-grid (quote ((daily today remove-match)
                                   #("----------------" 0 16 (org-heading t))
                               (0900 1100 1300 1500 1700))))
```

Can anyone see the problem here? Sorry I am not much of an elisp programmer.

Comment: `org-agenda-list` presumably expects the second element in list `org-agenda-time-grid` to be a list. It is instead a string. Maybe try wrapping it in `(...)` as a first attempt. If that doesn't help then you'll need to actually look at and understand the code a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec of the variable `org-agenda-time-grid` has changed recently. If you are using a recent version of org, then your setting is incorrect. Try reading the documentation of the variable with `C-h v org-agenda-time-grid RET`. I don't know what that `0 16 (org-heading t)` did in the old setting, but maybe you can try

```
(setq org-agenda-time-grid (quote 
                             ((daily today remove-match)
                              (0900 1100 1300 1500 1700)                                   
                              "......" "----------------"))))
```

as a first approximation and then tweak from there.

You should also try reading the `etc/ORG-NEWS` file which lists incompatible changes like the above for every release. When something breaks from one release to the next, the explanation can often be found there.

Comment: Okay great, this does work. Thanks for letting me know about the incompatible change. Haha, I am just an intermediate org-mode user, so I would never have found the solution to this issue without your direction. I will keep an eye on `ORG-NEWS`.